# Whats "Birth" field in stat command output

Tags: linux, ext4, command, stat

I'm using Fedora-16 with ext4.Suddenly with stat command I can see something called "Birth".

```
# stat history_file1.txt 
  File: `history_file1.txt'
  Size: 8944            Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d      Inode: 4192        Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
Access: 2012-01-18 18:11:10.799900150 +0530
Modify: 2012-01-18 18:11:10.867908793 +0530
Change: 2012-01-18 18:11:10.867908793 +0530
 Birth: -
```

search man page show instances of birth

> %w     Time of file birth, human-readable; - if unknown
>
> %W     Time of file birth, seconds since Epoch; 0 if unknown

Is this newly added field? where this field is stored with respect to inode ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the "birth" time of a specific file - the moment when it was created on the file system. This attribute is new to ext4 and is also known as `crtime` or `btime`, just google it. :)

[Here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/qVD1ZF4AdXEHJD4V3zoR) you can find a discussion regarding the stat command and the specific output you're seeing.

Comment: Cygwin's `stat(1)` also has this field, since Windows' NTFS stores the file's creation time.

Comment: BTW, Linux userspace tools don't seem to be able to read this time yet. At least not in Ubuntu 14.04. More details: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50177/birth-is-empty-on-ext4

Comment: Has that link somehow changed?  I cannot see the relevance.

Comment: How to display the missing birth / creation field: http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/

Comment: Same on 16.04, for what it's worth. I wonder if 18.04 has it yet?